# How to use relative path in launchSettings.json of .NET Core project?

Tags: .net-core

My launchSettings.json file:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "WinRedisSmcProxy": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
      "commandLineArgs": "dotnet C:\\Users\\KudeBJ\\Desktop\\redis-smc-proxy-prototype\\WinRedisSmcProxy\\WinRedisSmcProxy\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.0\\WinRedisSmcProxy.dll"
    }
  }
}
```

There is a problem in the code above. When the project is placed in another location instead of the desktop, the project will not run. This is because I used an absolute path in the configuration. Is there any way to change it to a relative one?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is it a requirement that the app opens in PowerShell?

Comment: @StephenKennedy I want to use PowerShell to execute my app instead of cmd.